How can I add a third axis on the right side of my graph and scale the index data properly?
I want to follow this example graph and display my index values as points and have a another axis for them on the right side but I want the second axis to be from -1 to 1 while keeping the left axis from 0-1. I believe I might need a axis line to display this properly but I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.
I can upload my graph and the example graph that I want to follow.
MyCode
MyData
ExampleGraph
MyGraph


create_plot <- function(data, seagrass, size_class) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Taxon, y = Proportion, fill = Source)) +
    # Bar graph
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = .7) +
    
    # Error bars
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Proportion - SE, ymax = Proportion + SE),
                  position = position_dodge(.7), width = 0.2) +
    
    # Point plot for Ivlev's Index
    geom_point(data = data %>% filter(Seagrass == seagrass, Size.Class == size_class),
               aes(x = Taxon, y = Index, color = "Ivlev's Index"),
               size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "black") +
    
    # Custom color for bars and points
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Diet" = "skyblue", "Seagrass" = "orange")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Ivlev's Index" = "red")) +
    
    # Labels
    labs(
      x = "Taxon",
      y = "Proportions",
      fill = "Legend",
      color = "Legend"
    ) +
    
    # Add title for the seagrass at the top (italicized)
    ggtitle(paste0("*", seagrass, "*")) +
    
    # Theme adjustments
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
      
      # Use element_markdown() to support markdown rendering for italics
      plot.title = element_markdown(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = "bold")
    )
}






Welcome to SO. Pictures of data are not very useful to us, as we cannot run code with that. Use e.g. dput(data) and paste the output in your question. Your plot doesn't seem to match the code you provided, as I don't see the code for the secondary axis. Have you looked at the (many) previous questions about secondary axes in ggplot?

Search here for `ggplot2 secondary axis" and you'll find many relevant answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805869/6851825

In lieu of making your question reproducible, you could probably find the answer in a variety of places: try here, try here, there's also tools like facet_wrap if you want the graph to be less misleading...
